Локальный Telegram Bot API Server
У меня есть телеграм бот на c#, через которого мне нужно отправить файл больше 50мб. Почитав вопросы про это понял, что нужно разворачивать локальный сервер для бота. Начал заниматься этим, прописал необходимые команды в PowerShell, заранее получил api-id и api-hash. Установка сервера вроде завершена, но как продолжить работу дальше - не знаю.
Команды, который я прописывал
git clone --recursive https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api.git
cd telegram-bot-api
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
./vcpkg.exe install gperf:x64-windows openssl:x64-windows zlib:x64-windows
cd ..
Remove-Item build -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -A x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=.. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ..
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
cd ../..
dir telegram-bot-api/bin/telegram-bot-api*

Еще бы хотелось узнать, как переподключить бота на свой локальный сервер, был бы признателен!

Здесь говорится, что он вам нужен только если у вас ограничения на скачивание и требуется качать файлы больше 2 Гб, ну и прочие увеличения лимитов.
Вы скачали локальный сервер и скомпилировали его. Дальше вам требуется, настроить автозапуск его и создать HTTPS Proxy:

The Telegram Bot API server accepts only HTTP requests, so a TLS termination proxy needs to be used to handle remote HTTPS requests.

После чего вас ждёт след. раздел
